# RoomDB: Migration without schema changes, I just want to drop the old Database and create from asset

Tags: java, android, android-room

My app doesn't need to keep user's custom data yet, all Data in Database is prepopulated via `createFromAsset()`. Now I want to make a version 2 that, when installed in device that already runs version 1, just drop all the data and feed it with `createFromAsset()` just like it already works for new installations. The point is version 2 has more data than version 1, but also some old data has been removed and replaced. Remember that user doesn't insert any data at all.

I tried combining `createFromAsset()` with `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` to no avail, even incrementing the schema version parameter in `@Database` annotation.

```
db = Room.databaseBuilder(mCtx, AppDatabase.class, "AppDatabase")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .createFromAsset("db/INIT_DB.sqlite3")
            .build();
```

This would just delete the data when updating the app, but not repopulating from asset as I expected. What is the most simple way to just drop the old database and repopulate it? Must I use migrations for this, even though the DB schema is still the same?

---

**EDIT:** After trying the `Callbacks` provided by @MikeT, if I install and run (by pressing Play on AndroidStudio) the "version2" of the App over an already installed "version1" (from the Google Play Store), the logs I obtain are as follows:

First, with `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`:

```
2022-06-13 XX:XX:XX.XXX 5859-5907/com.mydomain.myapp I/MYAPP_INFO: CALLBACK -> OnDestructiveMigration Called
2022-06-13 XX:XX:XX.XXY 5859-5907/com.mydomain.myapp I/MYAPP_INFO: CALLBACK -> OnOpen Called
```

...and now, providing the "empty migration" instead:

```
2022-06-13 XX:XX:XX.XXX 5859-5907/com.mydomain.myapp I/MYAPP_INFO: MIGRATION! Invoked Migration from V1 to V2
2022-06-13 XX:XX:XX.XXY 5859-5907/com.mydomain.myapp I/MYAPP_INFO: CALLBACK -> OnOpen Called
```

- The `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` approach just leads to the
  database getting empty when installing new version over the older, and the asset with the new DB data to be ignored.
- The approach in which I implement the empty migration (as well as the approach in which I try to check the "new version of the asset" and call delete() database from `ctx`), when installing new version over the older, just keeps using the old data, ignoring (once again) all the new data from the asset. **And here comes the funny part**: if, after launching the version2, I just hold my finger over my app's icon (OS level), "click" on "clean data" and then "delete all data" (emptying therefore the database itself), and **then open the app again**, the `createFromAsset()` kicks in!! **The whole point is** I'd like to spare final users the nuisance of deleting the old database themselves!

In both cases, if the installation is done without previous version on the device, the `.createFromAsset` works as expected.

### FOR THE RECORD

I am still using a single "asset name" for both versions of the app, and one single asset file: `INIT_DB.db` (is an SQLITE3 file anyway, but the SDK won't swallow it if I don't use `.db` extension... yet let's consider the "mock name" `INIT_DB.sqlite3` in the code samples to be valid...

Comment: The app is still a closed beta in Google Play Store... is this the moment to make it become an open beta? I wonder...

Comment: Perhaps, nothing did work because something related to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090883/3692177)? What if because of version 1 had the "Room meta-tables" inside the asset, everything became a mess and nothing works? If the error is related to the linked answer as I suspect, what am I supposed to do about it?

Comment: Maybe, instead of "getting rid of the RoomDB's meta-tables" in the asset, should I rather use them? Their structure is like `CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT); CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that the way to go is to detect the change in the asset.

Copying the asset and then comparing rows would be relatively inefficient. A more efficient approach, although a bit more complicated to manage would be to utilise the SQLITE **USER_VERSION** (or the ***APPLICATION_ID***).

This would entail setting the value in the latest asset to be greater than it was.

A changed (increased) **USER_VERSION** can be detected by just accessing the files (the current database and the asset) and reading the first 100 bytes and then extracting the 4 bytes at offset 60 (68 for the Application Id).

You can set the values using `PRAGMA user_version = n` for the **USER_VERSION** or (`PRAGMA application_id = n`) for the ***APPLICATION_ID*** via whatever tool you are using to maintain the database externally.

You would do this every time you instantiate the Database class **BEFORE** you build the database. If the asset version is greater (changed) then you delete the database and thus when the build is actioned then `createFromAsset` will copy the database from the asset.

I would suggest maintaining the database version in-line with the asset (although unlike the SQLite which would thrown an exception on a downgrade API Room doesn't seem to care about downgrade).

Here's a **working example**.

For the testing two asset databases have been created.

- The first (in the asset folder as V1Base) has rows with id's 1-5 inclusive and the second column name has V1 within the name.
- The second (in the asset folder as V2Base) has id's 2 and 4 from the first (1,3 and 5 have been deleted) and an additional 3 rows, id's 6, 8 and 10 and the name includes V2.

The asset folder (after the 2nd test run):-

[image]

- Obviously you would only have the 1 asset. However, for experimentation/testing/debugging the above allows easy manipulation of the files.

  - as the arrows show V1Base was copied to what is now INIT_DB.sqlite3_ORIGINAL (first run it was named INIT_DB.sqlite3) and V2Base was copied (after renaming INIT_DB.sqlite3 to INIT_DB.sqlite3_ORIGINAL) to INIT_DB.sqlite3

Only a single `@Entity` class was used that being **TheTable** :-

```
@Entity
class TheTable {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id=null;
    String name;
}
```

An `@Dao` interface with just a method to extract the data **TheTableDao**:-

```
@Dao
interface TheTableDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM thetable")
    List<TheTable> getAllTheTableRows();
}
```

A little more complex than normal `@Database` annotated abstract class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = {TheTable.class}, version = MainActivity.DATABASE_VERSION,exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract TheTableDao getTheTableDao();

    /* see  https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html */
    private static int SQLITE_HEADER_DATA_LENGTH = 100;
    private static int SQLITE_HEADER_USERVERSION_OFFSET = 60;
    private static int SQLITE_HEADER_USERVERSION_LENGTH = 4;


    private volatile static TheDatabase instance=null;
    static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            if (isNewAsset(context,MainActivity.ASSET_NAME,MainActivity.DATABASE_NAME)) {
                context.getDatabasePath(MainActivity.DATABASE_NAME).delete();
            }
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,MainActivity.DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    //.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .createFromAsset(MainActivity.ASSET_NAME,ppcb)
                    .addMigrations(v1_v2)
                    .addCallback(cb)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    static Migration v1_v2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            Log.d("MIGV1->V2","Invoked Migration from V1 to V2");
        }
    };

    static Callback cb = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            Log.d("CALLBACK","OnCreate Called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
            Log.d("CALLBACK","OnDestructiveMigration Called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            Log.d("CALLBACK","OnOpen Called");
        }
    };

    static PrepackagedDatabaseCallback ppcb = new PrepackagedDatabaseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpenPrepackagedDatabase(db);
            Log.d("PPCALLBACK","PrepackagedDatabase Called");
        }
    };

    private static boolean isNewAsset(Context context, String asset, String dbname) {
        File current_Db = context.getDatabasePath(dbname);
        if(!current_Db.exists()) return false; /* No Database then nothing to do */
        int current_Db_version = getDBVersion(current_Db);
        Log.d("DBINFO","isNewAsset has determined that the current database version is " + current_Db_version);
        if (current_Db_version < 0) return false; /* No valid version */
        int asssetVersion = getAssetVersion(context,asset);
        Log.d("DBINFO","isNewAsset has determined that the asset version is " + asssetVersion);
        if (asssetVersion > current_Db_version) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","isNewAsset has found that the asset version is greater than the current db version " + current_Db_version);
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.d("DBINFO","isNewAsset has found that the asset version is unchanged " + current_Db_version);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static int getDBVersion(File f) {
        int rv = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SQLITE_HEADER_DATA_LENGTH];
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(f);
            is.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            is.close();
            rv =  getVersionFromBuffer(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rv;
    }

    private static int getAssetVersion(Context context,String asset) {
        int rv = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SQLITE_HEADER_DATA_LENGTH];
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = context.getAssets().open(asset);
            is.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            is.close();
            rv = getVersionFromBuffer(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rv;
    }


    static int getVersionFromBuffer(byte[] buffer) {
        int rv = -1;
        if (buffer.length == SQLITE_HEADER_DATA_LENGTH) {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer,SQLITE_HEADER_USERVERSION_OFFSET,SQLITE_HEADER_USERVERSION_LENGTH);
            return  bb.getInt();
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

- **Notes**

  - Although `.allowMainThreadQueries` has been used, this is just for convenience, no reliance is made upon it's use.
  - what is important is the placement of the call of `isNewAsset`, this should be before the build.
  - the code is complicated by callbacks (suggested as it's then easier to understand what is going on; *remove them when happy*)
  - likewise some Logging
  - see the reference to the SQLite documentation regarding the header.

Last but not least and Activity to demonstrate **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "INIT_DB.sqlite3";
    public static final String ASSET_NAME = "db/" + DATABASE_NAME;

    TheDatabase db;
    TheTableDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getTheTableDao();
        Log.d("DBINFO","Extracting data");
        for (TheTable tt: dao.getAllTheTableRows()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","ID= " + tt.id + " NAME= " + tt.name);
        }
    }
}
```

- nothing special. However, constants placed here as it seemed more convenient for testing.

**First Run**

1. all assets bar **V1Base.db** and **V2Base.db** deleted.
2. the App uninstalled if it existed.
3. **VB1Base.db** copied and pasted as **INIT_DB.sqlite3**.
4. **DATABASE_VERSION** set to **1**.
5. Run and the log includes

:-

```
2022-06-12 09:50:37.804 D/DBINFO: Extracting data
2022-06-12 09:50:37.849 D/PPCALLBACK: PrepackagedDatabase Called
2022-06-12 09:50:37.905 D/CALLBACK: OnOpen Called
2022-06-12 09:50:37.910 D/DBINFO: ID= 1 NAME= V1Data001
2022-06-12 09:50:37.910 D/DBINFO: ID= 2 NAME= V1Data002
2022-06-12 09:50:37.911 D/DBINFO: ID= 3 NAME= V1Data003
2022-06-12 09:50:37.911 D/DBINFO: ID= 4 NAME= V1Data004
2022-06-12 09:50:37.911 D/DBINFO: ID= 5 NAME= V1Data005
```

- 

**Second Run**

1. Renamed **INIT_DB.sqlite3** to **INIT_DB.sqlite3_ORIGINAL**.
2. Copied and pasted **V2Base.db** to **INIT_DB.sqlite3**.
3. **DATABASE_VERSION** changed to **2**.
4. Run and the log includes

:-

```
2022-06-12 09:58:29.484 D/DBINFO: isNewAsset has determined that the current database version is 1
2022-06-12 09:58:29.484 D/DBINFO: isNewAsset has determined that the asset version is 2
2022-06-12 09:58:29.484 D/DBINFO: isNewAsset has found that the asset version is greater than the current db version 1
2022-06-12 09:58:29.521 D/DBINFO: Extracting data
2022-06-12 09:58:29.560 D/PPCALLBACK: PrepackagedDatabase Called
2022-06-12 09:58:29.571 D/MIGV1->V2: Invoked Migration from V1 to V2
2022-06-12 09:58:29.617 D/CALLBACK: OnOpen Called
2022-06-12 09:58:29.622 D/DBINFO: ID= 2 NAME= V1Data002
2022-06-12 09:58:29.622 D/DBINFO: ID= 4 NAME= V1Data004
2022-06-12 09:58:29.622 D/DBINFO: ID= 6 NAME= V2Data001
2022-06-12 09:58:29.622 D/DBINFO: ID= 8 NAME= V2Data002
2022-06-12 09:58:29.622 D/DBINFO: ID= 10 NAME= V2Data003
```

As can be seen this time (as the database exists) the versions are obtained, the change has been detected and thus the original database file has been deleted **AND** the data is now, as expected, from the newer asset.

**Third Run**

As a test when there is no new/updated asset, the log includes

:-

```
2022-06-12 11:23:57.249 D/DBINFO: isNewAsset has determined that the current database version is 2
2022-06-12 11:23:57.249 D/DBINFO: isNewAsset has determined that the asset version is 2
2022-06-12 11:23:57.250 D/DBINFO: isNewAsset has found that the asset version is unchanged 2
2022-06-12 11:23:57.287 D/DBINFO: Extracting data
2022-06-12 11:23:57.304 D/CALLBACK: OnOpen Called
2022-06-12 11:23:57.308 D/DBINFO: ID= 2 NAME= V1Data002
2022-06-12 11:23:57.308 D/DBINFO: ID= 4 NAME= V1Data004
2022-06-12 11:23:57.308 D/DBINFO: ID= 6 NAME= V2Data001
2022-06-12 11:23:57.308 D/DBINFO: ID= 8 NAME= V2Data002
2022-06-12 11:23:57.308 D/DBINFO: ID= 10 NAME= V2Data003
```

i.e. the asset and db are at the same level and the data remains as it was.

**Fourth Run**

App is uninstalled, so as per a new install, the log includes :-

```
2022-06-12 11:28:46.025 D/DBINFO: Extracting data
2022-06-12 11:28:46.073 D/PPCALLBACK: PrepackagedDatabase Called
2022-06-12 11:28:46.131 D/CALLBACK: OnOpen Called
2022-06-12 11:28:46.135 D/DBINFO: ID= 2 NAME= V1Data002
2022-06-12 11:28:46.135 D/DBINFO: ID= 4 NAME= V1Data004
2022-06-12 11:28:46.136 D/DBINFO: ID= 6 NAME= V2Data001
2022-06-12 11:28:46.136 D/DBINFO: ID= 8 NAME= V2Data002
2022-06-12 11:28:46.136 D/DBINFO: ID= 10 NAME= V2Data003
```

i.e. the latest asset is copied.

**Additional example of setting the **USER_VERSION** using DB Brwoser for SQLite**

1. Open the database file :-

[image: ![enter image description here]

2. Optional but suggested check the current version (here it is 1):-

[image]

3. Change the **USER_VERSION** to 2:-

[image]

- Note that there is no result in the result window but the log window shows that the command was successfully executed.

4. Check the **USER_VERSION** (strongly suggested) :-

[image]

5. SAVE (File/Close Database), quit DB Browser, restart DB Browser, Open the file and check the **USER_VERSION** again, then File/Close Database.
6. Copy the amended file into the asset replacing (suggest renaming until checked) the previous asset.

Comment: Let's say my "DB asset" is just a copy of the internal DB file. Yes, the Beta version is read-only, but I keep feeding the DB through a "custom alpha version" of the app, so the DB asset structure is "as is", just as the Entities generated it. That said, externally I just use `mysql3` in command-line to do whatever else I need to do with it. Should I consider this `USER_VERSION` and `APPLICATION_ID` to be some metadata autogenerated by SQLITE in Android? Sounds interesting... definetely, when I have some hours to deal again with my code, I want to try this out...

Comment: Btw, the fact that the asset's schema is a clone of the generated by Entities Room Database, also led me to discover that RoomDB added some "meta tables" for internal working... curious, isn't it?

Comment: @SebasSBM Room and android's SQLite API (which Room uses) creates two tables the former room_master_table which stores a hash of the schema (and I believe the version number), the latter creates android_metadata which is the locale. Neither are required in the asset as they will be generated. SQLite itself creates sqlite_master (the schema) and if AUTOINCREMENT is coded then sqlite_sequence (stores the highest allocated rowid per table with AUTOINCREMENT).

Comment: Good to know that I could just remove those meta-tables from the asset. It's actually the first app in which it launches with pre-populated data and, in my ignorance, I just kept them "just in case"... so, I better proceed to remove them from the asset...

Comment: @SebasSBM saying that you should never provide `room_master_table` in the asset, the hash is generated from the code, if it finds a difference then it considers that the schema has changed (never really tried to ascertain the implications).

Comment: What a shame, *it didn't work for me yet*... I added this `isNewAsset` conditional, but it just installs the new version reusing the DB installed by the old one... like if the method wasn't there... and when there is no previous version of the app, it installs the asset; just like before... might the Callbacks you provided give me some support now? I'mma try it out...

Comment: @SebasSBM you are changing the user_version in the asset? i.e. using `PRAGMA user_version = 1` (for the old/original) and then `PRAGMA user_version = 2` for the replacement (3 for the next ....)

Comment: I am afraid i'm not... I didn't understand this part at all... where am I supposed to place this `PRAGMA user_version` thing? Inside the SQLite file of the asset itself? On some config file? How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: @SebasSBM you need to run it as a query on the asset db file (mysql3 command line or get one of the sqlite tools, open the file in the tool and run it as a query). Tools such as DB Browser for SQlite, SQLiteStudio, Navicat for SQLite, DBeaver etc. It is the user_version that indicates the new asset (if the user_version is greater than the user_version in the installed db).

Comment: @SebasSBM I've added instructions to change the user_version using DB Browser for SQLite. **Again the whole process revolves around the user_version.**

Comment: Oh, `PRAGMA user_version` is a Sqlite3 instruction, and works by default I see... so, if I switch it to 2 in the asset, the `isNewAsset` will work correctly, right? I will try...

Comment: GREAT! Now it works so smoothly! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> What is the most simple way to just drop the old database and repopulate it?

Delete the database before you call the code in your question. For example, you could use [`deleteDatabase()` on `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context#deletedatabase)

Comment: It looks like an option... however, if I do so literally, wouldn't it delete the whole Database each time you open the app? That would be overkill, specially having in mind that some table has hundreds of thousands of rows! I just want to trigger the Delete when a new version of the app is installed.

Comment: @SebasSBM: "however, if I do so literally, wouldn't it delete the whole Database each time you open the app?" -- sorry, I should have been clearer. You would delete the whole database if, by some sort of indicator, you know that you have new data. Just as there is a schema version, you would maintain your own "content version". You could store the content version in the DB itself if you wanted. In that case, the flow would be: open the DB, read in the content version, and if your asset is newer, close/delete/reopen the DB. Or, if you prefer, track the current content version outside the DB.

Comment: I should also clarify that I am a noob with RoomDB migrations; I thought the RoomDB would have some pre-built functionality for this, but it doesn't seem so... I searched the web for lot of articles and documentation about it (even SO questions), but every example I find implies schema changes and/or keeping the data... so, long story short, I was hoping I could trigger this behaviour by increasing the DB version number... if I can't do it that way, how can I check reliably this thing? I guess I could just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table` and base the conditional on the result...

Comment: @SebasSBM: "I thought the RoomDB would have some pre-built functionality for this or something" -- Room has no way of knowing what content changes would cause you to want to delete and recreate the database. "I was hoping I could trigger this behaviour by increasing the DB version number" -- I do not know what you consider the "DB version number" to be. If you mean the schema version, that is for changing structure. `createFromAsset()` is only invoked when the database is *created*. If you want to force re-creation, you need to delete the database first, in your app code.

Comment: Also, I guess I could do some kind of migration that executes SQL like: `DROP DATABASE` and then execute a whole "sql dump" on the migration (the SQLDump would be huge however)... I was hoping there was a more simple, elegant way that this idea of mine...

Comment: @SebasSBM: "how can I check reliably this thing?" -- that is up to you. You could make decisions based on dates or row counts or something in the database. You could track your own "content version" number, akin to the schema version. You could make decisions based on your app's `versionCode` (i.e., if the previous `versionCode` is different than the now-current `versionCode`, delete and recreate the database).

Comment: "I don't know what you consider 'DB Version Number' to be. Quoting my own question: "...even incrementing the Version Number in `@Database` annotation. I guess I should edit my question to make this more clear...

Comment: @SebasSBM: The Room/Android SQLite term for that is "schema version".

Comment: "That is up to you" sounds fair. Even though I thought increasing the schema version (or otherwise somehow check for the `build.gradle` version number) would be the standard way, perhaps I was wrong guessing so... Doing the `SELECT COUNT(*)` seems reliable enough to me... So, if I am about to ignore Migrations for this, this functionality wouldn't belong to the DB instance singleton private constructor as I was trying to do... or would it? Anyway, I would need the DB instance first, then empty the tables and refill them (and all this with ad-hoc functionality ^^')...

Comment: ...or maybe yes, i should put it within the Singleton's constructor... it would make it bloat a little, but I still think this belongs to that layer... so, to implement it this way, I would still need to figure out howto insert the data from the asset (a Sqlite3 file exported from the app's db file itself). `Room.databaseBuilder.createFromAsset(dbfile)` made it easy for first install... I just can't figure out how to use that asset to refill... an alternative way would be to generate by myself an "SQL Dump" though...

Comment: I mean, I couldn't be able to do the `SELECT COUNT(*)` check without instantiating the DB with the buillder first... and your idea was based on do the delete before calling the databaseBuilder, right? But, if I could just do a check to the `build.gradle`'s VERSION_CODE, i might use the `ctx` for this as you suggested... I'll try to STFW to see if it is possible to check that value programatically...

Comment: No... VERSION_CODE would be updated before the `if` check gets done... what was I thinking? ^^'... so, the `SELECT COUNT(*) ` is the only idea I have to make a conditional to determine if it is "first update install" or not... and that, again, would imply to call `database Builder()[...]` before even being able to do the check... well, it still doesn't look elegant to me, but I just can't figure out other way to do it... and, if I do so, I think I should `DELETE FROM table` on each table instead, and then feed in the data...

Comment: Oh my goodness... it's even more complicated than I thought it would be... to get the count, I do it through LiveData! And, if I don't do so, I will have to create another `AsyncTask` just for this... I just can't access the LifecycleOwner from the Singleton, which I need in order to implement a new anonymous Observer through the LiveData result of the check... it's like being in a labirynth, and every step that I make makes me feeling even more lost...

Comment: ...the alternative in this "MVVM-Repository-DatabaseSingleton" architecture that I am using, would be to place this new functionality in an upper layer (the ViewModel, for example), but that sounds too hacky to me!! Or even implement it in MainActivity.java (even worse!! making a view dealing with DB, non-UI functionality)... there must be another way...