# Android Room where is DB version stored?

Tags: android, database, migration, android-room

Refering to: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#migrations

I want Room to remove my version 2 database and install a brand new version 3 database when updating from version 2 to version 3.

It says that for fallback migration to work you need "a prepackaged database file that is on version 3." when migrating from version 2 to 3.

Where is that version stored? The createFromAsset method takes a .db file and I cannot find a version in there. There is only the identifier_string which relates to the schema but can stay the same across versions.

Or is a new version only valid if the schema changes? How would I then trigger a migration if I e.g. just added some more entries to my database (e.g. by adding a new product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 places where the version number is stored.

In the code, i.e. the version number that you specify in the @Database annotation.

And in the actual **[database header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)**, the first 100 bytes of the database file.

The specific location, within the header, an offset of 60 bytes from the start and is 4 bytes in length. SQLite calls the the **[user_version](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#user_version_number)**

It can be retrieved and or set by using the **[user_version PRAGMA](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#user_version_number)**, it could also be set or retrieved by opening the file itself and accessing or manipulating the value in the file.

The **SupportSQliteDatabase** class also has the methods [**getVersion**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#getVersion()) and [**setVersion**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#setVersion(int)).

- These two would probably not be of use though.

Some of the available SQLite Tools, which you would typically use for creating and maintaining a pre-packaged database, allow this to be easily changed

- e.g. DB Browser for SQlite has :-

  - [image]

> Or is a new version only valid if the schema changes? How would I then trigger a migration if I e.g. just added some more entries to my database (e.g. by adding a new product)?

Simply updating the version number in the @Database annotation is all that is required to initiate a Migration, a schema change itself does not trigger the Migration.

Rather a schema change will be recognised as Room generates a hash of the schema as part of the code. This hash is compared against a hash that is stored in the database in the table room_master. The hashes mismatch them Room sees a change and will then expect that a Migration is provided, if not then an exception is raised and the App crashes.

The Migration can do nothing if required.

AutoMigrations are similar except that the Migration code is generated automatically, although it needs in the circumstances of an ambiguity (e.g. a column rename) to be provided with additional information via migration specs.

Obviously you cannot use a manual and an AutoMigration together.

Comment: Thank you so much for your well-written answer! Finally I know where the version is stored. I have a follow-up question though. If I understand correctly, the AutoMigration would simply keep the old database's entries if the schema has not been changed. In my use case I maintain a list of products with a name, price etc. The database also includes a column "Favorite" so users can mark a product as favorite. Its default value is false. How can I add new products to the database in the future but also persist the "Favorite" column so users don't lose their data?

Comment: I initialize the database using createFromAsset. This works perfectly fine for the first initialization. The only migration workaround I found was using fallbackToDestructiveMigration and update the asset file. That makes sure that all new products are included, but also deletes all user data e.g. by resetting the "Favorite" column.

Comment: @Lexusminds you might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581361/roomdb-migration-without-schema-changes-i-just-want-to-drop-the-old-database-a/72588665#72588665 (or check some of my other answers).